# New line on function argument list while using php-cs-fixer and PHPCodeSniffer

Tags: php, phpcs, php-cs-fixer

We are using both php-cs-fixer and PHPCodeSniffer tools for our coding standards. Both can be conflicted when having different rules. We were able to get a balanced result except for one rule. Warning thrown by PHP Code Sniffer :

```
phpcs: Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last content on the line
phpcs: Closing parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be on a line by itself
```

Those 2 warnings are probably caused by PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature rule. We are not able to fix this automatically with our php-cs-fixer custom configuration :

https://pastebin.com/F4fpUTek

**An example of the required result** :
After fixing :

```
$response = $this->client->post('users/authenticate', [
    'form_params' => [
        'email'    => $email,
        'password' => $password,
    ],
]);
```

Expected output :

```
$response = $this->client->post(
    'users/authenticate',
    [
        'form_params' => [
            'email'       => $email,
            'password'    => $password,
        ],
    ]
);
```

Is there a way to achieve the previous output ?

Comment: Not all rule violations can be fixed by the fixer. What's your question?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Is there a way to achieve the expected output with php-cs-fixer ?

Comment: Does the triggered sniff indicate that it is fixable?

Comment: Good question, I just checked the code itself. Seems to be added to FixableErrors around line 400 : https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/PEAR/Sniffs/Functions/FunctionCallSignatureSniff.php

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by using the adequate tools. We realized **php-cs-fixer** does not work as well as **phpcb** with PHP Codesniffer. As mentionned in the Github page :

"PHP_CodeSniffer is a set of two PHP scripts; the main phpcs script that tokenizes PHP, JavaScript and CSS files to detect violations of a defined coding standard, and a second phpcbf script to automatically correct coding standard violations. PHP_CodeSniffer is an essential development tool that ensures your code remains clean and consistent."

https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

We used phpcb and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using php-cs-fixer, you might be interested in the "on_multiline" option of the "method_argument_space" rule:

> Defines how to handle function arguments lists that contain newlines.

[https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:3.38|fixer:method_argument_space](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:3.38%7Cfixer:method_argument_space)

[image]